# HTML5 - AVC/MP3 video playable?

Tags: html, video

i have a video file (avi with avc+mp3). Is it possible to play this via the HTML5 video-tag?

i have tested it in Internet Explorer 9 but it will not work! Is it because the audio codec mp3 is not supported or is it the "video Codec-Profile "HighL3.0"?

[image: Videoinformations]

Answer (score 1):

Edited to fix misunderstanding

I suggest you do some reading about the ongoing codec wars, or [look at this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).  Basically, some browsers accept only videos with a MP4 container, H.264-encoded video, and AAC-encoded audio (low-complexity profile); some browsers accept only videos with a WebM container, VP8-encoded video, and ogg-vorbis-encoded audio.

MP4/H.264 seems to be winning the war, but at the moment you'll need both for complete browser support.

Comment: But AVC is the videocodec into the mp4 container file. And this works with the AAC-audio codec in the mp4 container, i think and i am sure...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (I don't usually see H.264 referred to as "AVC").  MP4 files with H.264-encoded video usually have AAC-encoded audio, so I would recommend using AAC, not MP3, as the audio codec.

Comment: One more thing: use the low-complexity profile for AAC audio.

Answer (score 0):

Modern [browsers which support](http://caniuse.com/#search=video) `<video>` use WebM, MP4/H.264 and OGG video format. So you can't use AVI for HTML5 video. There is no unique format which is supported by all browsers. The only solution is to convert file to supported formats and use `<video>` like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">   <!-- IE, Chrome, Safari, Android -->
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">   <!-- Firefox, Chrome, Opera -->
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm"> <!-- Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Android -->
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: or use a mixture of HTML5 and Flash

Comment: And what audio codec must i need when i convert this video to MP4 with H.264 video codec?

Comment: In my oppinion, Flash is the best solution for non-HTML5, old browsers... modern one doesn't need Flash :)

Comment: I recommend [Free video converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/). It's free and you don't need to worry about codecs! :)